# Sqlite statement insert - wrong column order?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

my insert command is

```
 long insertID = database.insert(TrackDBHelper.TAB_1, null, values);
```

TAB_1 is the Name of the table and values are five datas of ContentValues
which are correctly put

the error message is

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TRACKS (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO TRACKS(Picture,NAME,CHANGE,LANG,Numbers) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

But the table names are Name, LANG, Numbers, CHANGE, Picture

I didn't anywhere Change the order of the rows?

Help would be great

Here is how db is created

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE="CREATE TABLE "+TAB_1+
        " ("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMERY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        COLUMN_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
        COLUMN_LANG+" INT NOT NULL, "+
        COLUMN_NUMBERS+" INT NOT NULL, "+
        COLUMN_CHANGE+" INT NOT NULL, "+
        COLUMN_PICTURE+" TEXT NOT NULL );";
```

Comment: show the code of how you create your table

Comment: Add this to your question not in comment

Comment: I don't think your table is created that . Check that first

Comment: _id is null every time but I didn't see the mistake :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very silly mistake that you have done. Your spelling for primary is wrong when defining Primary key auto increment

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh - so sad :( I'm debugging for hours - so thank you very much - sometimes you need someone :))